# Custom Build Rule fails after converting to VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msvc12, build-rules

I need to integrate a legacy VS2008 project into my VS2013 solution. This project uses some custom build rules which initially worked after converting the .vcproj to a .vcxproj. However, when doing a fresh checkout of the project including the .vcxproj, the project file can no longer be opened.

I've tracked it down to this issue:

The project file references a couple of custom build rules like this:

```
<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  <Import Project="..\..\..\tools\build\ms_mc.props" />
  (8 similar lines follow)
</ImportGroup>
```

However, the ms_mc.props file is not present, but there is a ms_mc.rule file. If I convert the VS2008 solution with VS2013 (and assumably also if I opened it in VS2008, which I don't possess), the ms_mc.props file (plus a .targets and a .xml file) is created. However, if I delete that file and open the converted VS2013 project, the file does not get created.

I realized, in the old .vcproj, the corresponding lines are

```
<ToolFiles>
  <ToolFile RelativePath="..\..\..\tools\build\ms_mc.rule" />
  (8 similar lines follow)
</ToolFiles>
```

Why does VS2008 reference the .rule file and VS2013 imports the .props file without specifying the .rule file? And more importantly: How can I make this work again?

The .rule and .props file are added for reference

---

ms_mc.rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VisualStudioToolFile
    Name="MS MC"
    Version="8,00"
    >
    <Rules>
        <CustomBuildRule
            Name="MS_MC"
            DisplayName="Microsoft Message Catalogue Compiler"
            CommandLine="mc [Verbose] [inputs] [RCIncludePath] [CIncludePath]"
            Outputs="[$RCIncludePath]\$(InputName).rc;[$RCIncludePath]\$(InputName).h"
            FileExtensions="*.mc"
            ExecutionDescription="Compiling Message Catalogue $(InputName).mc"
            >
            <Properties>
                <BooleanProperty
                    Name="Verbose"
                    DisplayName="Verbose"
                    Description="Gives verbose output. (-v)"
                    Switch="-v"
                />
                <StringProperty
                    Name="RCIncludePath"
                    DisplayName="RC include file path"
                    Description="Gives the path of where to create the RC include file and the binary message resource files it includes. (-r [pathspec])"
                    Switch="-r [value]"
                    DefaultValue=".\"
                />
                <StringProperty
                    Name="CIncludePath"
                    DisplayName="C include file path"
                    Description="Gives the path of where to create the include header file. (-h [pathspec])"
                    Switch="-h [value]"
                    DefaultValue=".\"
                />
            </Properties>
        </CustomBuildRule>
    </Rules>
</VisualStudioToolFile>
```

ms_mc.props (after Conversion to VS2013):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup
    Condition="'$(MS_MCBeforeTargets)' == '' and '$(MS_MCAfterTargets)' == '' and '$(ConfigurationType)' != 'Makefile'">
    <MS_MCBeforeTargets>Midl</MS_MCBeforeTargets>
    <MS_MCAfterTargets>CustomBuild</MS_MCAfterTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MS_MCDependsOn
      Condition="'$(ConfigurationType)' != 'Makefile'">_SelectedFiles;$(MS_MCDependsOn)</MS_MCDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <MS_MC>
      <Verbose>False</Verbose>
      <RCIncludePath>.\</RCIncludePath>
      <CIncludePath>.\</CIncludePath>
      <CommandLineTemplate>mc [Verbose] [inputs] [RCIncludePath] [CIncludePath]</CommandLineTemplate>
      <Outputs>%(RCIncludePath)\%(Filename).rc;%(RCIncludePath)\%(Filename).h</Outputs>
      <ExecutionDescription>Compiling Message Catalogue %(Filename).mc</ExecutionDescription>
    </MS_MC>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/21/quick-help-on-vs2010-custom-build-rule.aspx) for VS2010 which states the following:

> Custom build rule is a build feature introduced in VS2005. It provides the ability for the users to easily Plug-In third party tools to use in their build process. The custom build rule is defined by “.rules” files.

and more importantly

> In VS2010, due to the migration to MSBuild, the information in the rules file is represented by three files: .XML, .props and .targets files.

This basically means that the .XML, .props and .targets files are in fact not created by VS2008; instead, they are a replacement of the old .rules file format since VS2010. Using this information, I can now safely check in those new files without breaking the VS2008 solution. I might have to adapt the new files manually in order to make them work as before, as also mentioned in the blog.